# Is there an Amazon community AMI for Hadoop/HBase?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hbase, amazon-ami

I would like to test out Hadoop & HBase in Amazon EC2, but I am not sure how complicate it is. Is there a stable community AMI that has Hadoop & HBase installed? I am thinking of something like [bioconductor AMI](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/bioconductor-cloud-ami/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend using [Amazon's Elastic MapReduce](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) service, especially if you already have an AWS/EC2 account. The reasons are:

1. EMR comes with a working Hadoop/HBase cluster "out of the box" - you don't need to tune anything to get Hadoop/HBase working. It Just Works(TM).
2. Amazon EC2's networking is quite different from what you are likely used to. It has, AFAIK, a 1-to-1 NAT where the node sees its own private IP address, but it connects to the outside world on a public IP. When you are manually building a cluster, this causes problems - even using software like Apache Whirr or BigTop specifically for EC2.
3. An AMI alone is not likely to help you get a Hadoop or HBase cluster up and running - if you want to run a Hadoop/HBase cluster, you will likely have to spend time tweaking the networking settings etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Suman. I wouldn't have found out about cluster nature of the problem.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, if it's just for testing then EMR sounds like the easiest approach compared to a more DIY solution like Whirr.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there isn't, but you should be able to easily deploy on EC2 using [Apache Whirr](http://whirr.apache.org/) which is a very good alternative.

Here is [a good tutorial](http://www.bigfastblog.com/run-the-latest-whirr-and-deploy-hbase-in-minutes) to do this with Whirr, as the tutorial says you should be able to do this in minutes !

The key is creating a recipe like this:

```
whirr.cluster-name=hbase
whirr.instance-templates=1 zk+nn+jt+hbase-master,5 dn+tt+hbase-regionserver
whirr.provider=ec2
whirr.identity=${env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
whirr.credential=${env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
whirr.hardware-id=c1.xlarge
whirr.image-id=us-east-1/ami-da0cf8b3
whirr.location-id=us-east-1
```

You will then be able to launch your cluster with:

```
bin/whirr launch-cluster --config hbase-ec2.properties
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detail answer. I'll keep the question open for a couple more days just in case somebody knows about a readily available, but your answer definitely gives me a great starting point.